# Filtering a dictionary by multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I've had a difficult time formulating a "pythony" way of filtering a dictionary.

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
'217': {'586': 2.0, '578': 5.0, '172': 1.0, '1222': 1.0, '597': 4.0, '1303': 2.0, '195': 5.0, ...}
'660': {'176': 4.0, '174': 3.0, '231': 5.0, '233': 4.0, '797': 4.0, '541': 3.0, '27': 1.0, '210': 4.0, ...}
```

and so on.

Then I have a  list of strings:

```
['2', '4', '17', '21', '22', '24', '27', '28', '29', '33', '39', ...]
```

What I want to achieve is a filtered dictionary where only the tuples with any values in the list of strings exist. I've managed to do exactly that but with using only one string as a requirement and it looks like this:

```
filtered_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in my_dict.iteritems() if my_list[0] in v}
```

However if I remove the [0] I get the following error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Here are some expected output values:

```
'115 : {'174': 4.0, '172': 4.0, '27': 3.0, '183': 5.0, '180': 3.0, '1039': 5.0, ... }

'212' : {'4': 3.0, '473': 4.0, '208': 5.0, '123': 4.0, '476': 3.0, '474': 4.0, ...}
```

As you can see, the third value in the first tuple has '27' in it which was in my_list.
The first value in the second tuple has the value '4' which also was in my_list.

I would very much appreciate any sort of help on this.

Thank you!

Comment: You should add some expected output values..

Comment: `... if my_list[0] in v` means if the first item is in v.. maybe you want to do `... for item in my_list if item in v` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a set, keeping pairs if value is not disjoint from the set:

```
st = {'2', '4', '17', '21', '22', '24', '27', '28', '29', '33', '39'}

filtered_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in my_dict.iteritems() if not st.isdisjoint(v)}
```

They will only be disjoint if they do not share at least one element:

```
In [6]: st ={1,2,3}

In [7]: v = [1,4,5]

In [8]: st.isdisjoint(v)
Out[8]: False

In [11]: v = [7,4,5]

In [12]: st.isdisjoint(v)
Out[12]: True
```

It is somewhat equivalent to:

```
st = {'2', '4', '17', '21', '22', '24', '27', '28', '29', '33', '39'}

filtered_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in my_dict.iteritems() if any(val in st for val in v)}
```

Where if [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) element from v is in the set we keep the elements.

Worst case we check `len(v)` elements against the set, iterating over the `mylist` elements and checking if x is in v  is `O(len(my_list))` for every case and also creates the same k,v pairing every time you get a match.

If we add a dict with more match keys and add the pairs to  to a list, you can see what happens:

```
In [22]: my_list  = ['2', '4', '17', '21', '22', '24', '27', '28', '29', '33', '39']

In [23]: my_dict = {'217': {'586': 2.0, '578': 5.0, '172': 1.0, '1222': 1.0, '597': 4.0, '1303': 2.0, '195': 5.0},
   ....:            '660': {'176': 4.0, '174': 3.0, '231': 5.0, '233': 4.0, '797': 4.0, '541': 3.0, '27': 1.0, '210': 4.0},
   ....:            '661': {'2': 4.0, '4': 3.0, '29': 5.0, '17': 4.0, '39': 4.0, '541': 3.0, '27': 1.0, '210': 4.0}}


In [24]: print [(k,v) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems() for x in my_list if x in v]
[('661', {'541': 3.0, '39': 4.0, '2': 4.0, '4': 3.0, '17': 4.0, '210': 4.0, '27': 1.0, '29': 5.0}), ('661', {'541': 3.0, '39': 4.0, '2': 4.0, '4': 3.0, '17': 4.0, '210': 4.0, '27': 1.0, '29': 5.0}), ('661', {'541': 3.0, '39': 4.0, '2': 4.0, '4': 3.0, '17': 4.0, '210': 4.0, '27': 1.0, '29': 5.0}), ('661', {'541': 3.0, '39': 4.0, '2': 4.0, '4': 3.0, '17': 4.0, '210': 4.0, '27': 1.0, '29': 5.0}), ('661', {'541': 3.0, '39': 4.0, '2': 4.0, '4': 3.0, '17': 4.0, '210': 4.0, '27': 1.0, '29': 5.0}), ('661', {'541': 3.0, '39': 4.0, '2': 4.0, '4': 3.0, '17': 4.0, '210': 4.0, '27': 1.0, '29': 5.0}), ('660', {'797': 4.0, '27': 1.0, '541': 3.0, '210': 4.0, '176': 4.0, '174': 3.0, '231': 5.0, '233': 4.0})]
```

Because there are 7 matches, we get the same pairing seven times, you won't get dupes in a dict but you will have to iterate len(my_list) times  and create the pairing length of `x in v` being True times. As the length of my_list grows the run time will increase accordingly.

Just making my_list 1000 elements there is a considerable difference:

```
In [35]: len(my_list)
Out[35]: 1000

In [36]: %%timeit
   ....: st = set(my_list)
   ....: {k: v for (k, v) in my_dict.iteritems() if not st.isdisjoint(v)}
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.9 µs per loop
In [37]: timeit {k:v for k,v in my_dict.iteritems() for x in my_list if x in v}
10000 loops, best of 3: 136 µs per loop
```

Almost all that time is spent in the set creation, if you use a set from the start it runs 100 times faster:

```
In [40]: timeit {k: v for (k, v) in my_dict.iteritems() if not st.isdisjoint(v)}

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 µs per loop
```

Comment: Alright both your suggestions seem to have worked great. Although I think maybe haifzhans solution was easier for me to understand !

Comment: @Super_Soet,  I don't think you fully understand what the difference is, I added an example to the answer of why you should be using the set

Comment: Aha I see. So your suggestion stops searching for more values that are in that key as soon as it finds one. Where as haifzhans suggestion continues to search through the rest of the list even though it has already found a match, making every other check after the first match unnecessary ?
Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: @Super_Soet, exactly, you only care if there is a match, once you get one you move on to the next k/v pair, what else is in the list is irrelevant

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you for taking the time to explain !

Comment: @Super_Soet, no worries, might not make a great deal of difference here but if you have a large amount of data  to process then there would be a significant difference.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your question correctly, you need to traverse list `mylist`  and compare each element with values of dictionary `mydict`

`{k:v for k,v in mydict.iteritems() for x in mylist if x in v}`

1) k:v for k,v in mydict.iteritems() is iterating your dictionary pair by pair.

2) for x in mylist if x in v is iterating mylist and checks whether mylist element `in` inner dictionary v, therefore checks `x in v` is equal to checking `x in v.keys()` which x in the keys of v

Comment: You are checking every single element from mylist every iteration regardless of whether you get a match at the first , second, third etc.. which also means you are creating the same k/v pairing  times `x in v` being True.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes. it is nested loop for the dict and list